# Attributes on merge tag

Tags: android, layout

I have the class

```
    public class CompactFeedItemView extends LinearLayout {
        public CompactFeedItemView(Context context,MyObject a) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.compactfeedviewitem,this,true);
        }
}
```

And then I have the compactfeedviewitem.xml file:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id='@+id/feedViewItemOuterLayout' 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/compactfeedborder"
    >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/feedItemIcon"
        android:src="@drawable/missing" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />
</merge>
```

And this works, and the imageview is merged in and added as child, BUT it is ignoring the
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
attributes from the merge tag.

So how do I merge in attributes, or is this not possible?
I could change  to . That will work, but then I end up with an extra useless LinearLayout element for each CompactFeedItemView i create. Which is exactly what I wanted to avoid with merge.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, because the whole point of a `merge` tag is to remove unnecessary `ViewGroup` objects and specifying attributes (like margin) would require a `ViewGroup` object to be placed in the view hierarchy.

Comment: But there is a ViewGroup object. CompactFeedItemView is a ViewGroup object, so I would expect it to merge the attributes from <merge> into that group. There is no reason not to do that.